# Instantiating ViewModel that needs application parameter causes a render problem in a composable preview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

My preview of a composable is not working and displaying this render problem :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to class android.app.Application
```

My preview code :

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MainScreenPrev() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val application = context.applicationContext as Application

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val myViewModel = MyViewModel(application)

    MainScreen(navController = navController, myViewModel = myViewModel)
}
```

MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel that has application as parameter. Most examples online show this as the proper way to get application inside a composable. Is there a better practice to get this preview to work ?

Comment: Have you find any solution to this?

Comment: No, I decided to bypass this with an emulator rather then use compose preview. Might do that and use hilt to inject things rather then extending android view model until I figure out the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also end up creating a factory constructor for the view model. And for preview I am implementing interface and mocking fake ViewModel data.